# Python: Sorted representation of dict of lists, sorted by number of elements in list, after removing duplicates

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
example_dict = {
        0: [(1,2),(3,4),(3,4),(4,5)],
        1: [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)],
        2: [(4,5),(7,8)]}
```

I would like to get a sorted representation of this dictionary by number of elements in each list **after 'temporarily' removing duplicates** (only for the purpose of sorting, I don't want to delete remove tuples). So sorted `example_dict` would have the following (ascending) order of keys: 2,0,1.

Is there any efficient, *Pythonic* way to do this?

Comment: Python dictionaries are inherently unordered.  You can't sort them.  (Although you can get a sorted representation of their contents as key-value pairs.)

Comment: You're right, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print sorted(example_dict,key=lambda x: len(set(example_dict[x])))
```

Output:

```
[2, 0, 1]
```

Or if you want the dictionary items sorted as a list of tuples:

```
print sorted(example_dict.items(),key=lambda x: len(set(x[1])))
```

Output:

```
[(2, [(4, 5), (7, 8)]), (0, [(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5)]), (1, [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best data structure for you probably is [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Then you can iterate through your dictionary in sorted order.

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [2]: example_dict_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(example_dict.items(), key=lambda tup: len(set(tup[1]))))

In [3]: example_dict_sorted[0]
Out[3]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5)]

In [4]: example_dict_sorted[1]
Out[4]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]

In [5]: example_dict_sorted[2]
Out[5]: [(4, 5), (7, 8)]

In [6]: for key in example_dict_sorted:
   ...:     print key
2
0
1
```